# ООП переопределение метода

Tags: unity3d

Есть скрипт, который висит на слайдере  и  меняет его значение value, когда  курсор наведен на него (PointerEnter) после завершения, когда value = 1 должно выполняться всё что находится за этим циклом, это работает, но когда вот так переопределяю, при наведении на слайдер он сразу цикл пропускает и панели открывает мне PanelQuest [0].SetActive (true);  Не дождавшись пока цикл дойдет до конца и значение будет 1, а сразу при наведении срабатывает. Что не так сделал?
http://piccy.info/view3/11534754/7302d0a9285a259a95a9779fe5cd37b8/orig/

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class VRSlider : MonoBehaviour {

public float fillTime = 2f;
public float fillTime2 = 0.2f;
public float timer;
protected Slider _Slider;
protected bool GazeAt;
protected Coroutine fillBarRoutine;

public  void PointerEnter18(){ //При наведении 
    GazeAt = true;
    fillBarRoutine = StartCoroutine(FillBar18());
}

public virtual IEnumerator FillBar18()
{
    Slider _Slider = GetComponent<Slider> ();
    timer = 0f;
    while (timer < fillTime)
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        _Slider.value = timer / fillTime;

        yield return null;

        if (GazeAt)
            continue;

        timer = 0f;
        _Slider.value = 0f;
        yield break;
    }

}
    public void PointerExit()    { // курсор находится не на слайдере, сброс
    Slider _Slider = GetComponent<Slider> ();
    GazeAt = false;
    if (fillBarRoutine != null)
    {
        StopCoroutine(fillBarRoutine);
    }

    timer = 0f;
    _Slider.value = 0f;
}
}
```

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WindowResultCompileSliders : VRSlider {
public GameObject[] PanelQuest;

public override IEnumerator FillBar18 ()
{

    PanelQuest [1].SetActive (false);
    //PanelQuest [2].SetActive (false);
    PanelQuest [0].SetActive (true);

    return base.FillBar18 ();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тоесть

```
    PanelQuest [1].SetActive (false);
    //PanelQuest [2].SetActive (false);
    PanelQuest [0].SetActive (true);
```

надо запустить после цикла? 
Так не?

```
public override IEnumerator FillBar18 ()
    {
        yield return base.FillBar18();
        PanelQuest [1].SetActive (false);
        //PanelQuest [2].SetActive (false);
        PanelQuest [0].SetActive (true);

    }
```

Comment: Всё верно, спасибо большое